# How to use Paged.js in Vue.js3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagedjs

index.html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/pagedjs/dist/paged.polyfill.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

App.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
   import { Previewer } from 'pagedjs';
</script>
<template>
  <div class="pagedjs_pages">
     Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consec.......
     hellllloooooo!!!!!
  </div>
  <!-- hellllloooooo!!! disappeared  -->
```

css in App.vue

```css
@page {
  size: A4 landscape;
 // tried size: 297mm 210mm;
}
```

result:

what I expected is an A4 landscape page, but it seems like, the "page" is landscape, which is correct,  but the content is like vertical A4, and not showing my full content, cut the rest content at bottom, which part did I miss?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found another [reference](https://github.com/rogerwang2014/vite-vue3-explore), for anyone who needs it.

```js
// App.vue

<script lang="ts">
  import { onMounted } from 'vue';
  
  onMounted(()=>{
    let paged = new Previewer();
  
    let flow = paged.preview().then((flow) => {
      console.log("Rendered", flow.total, "pages.");
    })
  });
</script>

<template ref="template">
  <div>hello</div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  @import 'pagedjs.scss';
</style>
```

```scss
// pagedjs.scss

@page {
  size: A4 landscape !important;

  @top-left {
    content: "should be shown on the top-left";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #979797;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
// styling....
```